# Como eu posso verificar se a ultima posição do array foi preenchida?

Tags: php, array

Como eu posso verificar se a ultima posição do array foi preenchida?

Tentei a função `array_pop` mas parece que ela corta o elemento do `array`, eu quero apenas verificar se na última posição do `array` existe alguma coisa...

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre  Java, php, mysql, asp ou php? Considere editar sua pergunta, pois ela é um chamativo para votos negativos, visto que não está apresentada de forma clara. (observação: não fui eu quem negativei)

Comment: Desculpe, já alterei, é em PHP

Comment: existe alguma coisa? Seria verificar se o valor não null, false ou 0? Porque se for "existir", você teria que saber qual a posição exata, poderia mostrar o que já fez?

Comment: Vou dar um +1, pois essa é uma dúvida que as vezes o pessoal que tá começando costuma ter.

Answer (score 7):

Pode usar a função `end()` para pegar o último elemento do array e verificar se ele tem valor ou não.

```
$arr = [1,2,3, null];

$ultimo = end($arr);

if($ultimo){
    echo 'tem valor: '. $ultimo;
}else{
    echo 'é vazio';
}
```

Comment: aff, foi mais rápido

Comment: @WallaceMaxters quase um minuto de diferença :P ta comendo poeira.

Comment: era exatamente o que eu queria, muito obrigado galera

Comment: @ViniciusAquino você pode marcar uma das respostas como útil se resolveu o problema. Sugiro marcar essa do rray, já que ele respondeu primeiro :D

Answer (score 5):

Eu faria assim:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];

$end = end($array);

if ($end) {
    echo "A última posição é {$end}";
}
```

Observação: A função `end` só funciona com `arrays` armazenados em variáveis, já que a mesma espera uma parâmetro passado por referência.

Se tiver problemas com isso, a forma que eu costumo resolver isso é criando uma função que serve como um "wrapper" para poder driblar esse "problema" no PHP:

```
function last(array $array) {
   return end($array);
}

last([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // int(5)
```

Comment: obrigado, era exatamente oq eu queria

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra alternativa é obter o valor por índice, usando o [`count`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) para obter o total de elementos e subtrair por *1*:

```
$array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

if (($indice = count($array)) > 0) { // Se for um índice válido
    $ultimoValor = $array[$indice - 1];

    echo $ultimoValor;
}
```

Comment: O problema desse código aí é que se o `count` retornar `0`, o `-1` vai gerar um "undefined index". Além do mais, o `array` pode não ser numérico (como uma lista do `Python`), o que vai gerar mais dores de cabeça. É claro, seu exemplo vai dar certo pois o `array` foi declarado como numérico. Mas talvez, por segurança, fosse necessário usar `array_values` para resetar com um `isset`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Valeu. :) Já arrumei o código, veja se está melhor agora.

Comment: Isso aí funciona :D +1